# If an element is the same in more than one array, randomly choose one array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 1 multidimensional array:

```
$adverts = array(array('text'=>'test', 'location' => 'location1'), array('text'=>'test', 'location' => 'location2'), array('text'=>'test', 'location' => 'location1'))
```

As you can see, two arrays inside that multidimensional array contain the same text for the `location` element.

How would I detect this, and randomly choose one of them in a foreach loop that looks something like this:

```
foreach ($adverts as $advert)
        {

            if ($hookName == $advert['advert_location'] && XenForo_Helper_Criteria::userMatchesCriteria($advert['user_criteria']))
            {
                $contents .= $advert['advert_code'];
            }
        }
```

(I know the arrays don't match)

In that foreach loop, each the `location` of each array in the multidimensional array is being checked against a predefined value. If more than one of the array's inside the multidimensional array have the same `location` I want to only use one of them - in other words, contents doesn't get modified for the same location more than once.

However, it should use a random array from each of the matching values.

Is this possible, did you understand it and how would it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just group them bases on location then select at random each time you loop

```
$group = array_reduce($adverts, function ($a, $b) {
    $a[$b['location']][] = $b;
    return $a;
});

$contents = array();
foreach($group as $adverts) {
    $contents[] = $adverts[mt_rand(0, count($adverts) - 1)];
}

print_r($contents);
```

[See Example](https://eval.in/36652)

Comment: It would be IMHO preferable to use `array_walk` instead of `array_reduce` because that communicates what's going to happen better. Of course that's a very minor detail.

Comment: `array_walk` would either modify the array or force me to use `global` that  is why i used `array_reduce` ... Can you given an example ?

Comment: @Baba: You don't really need either one.  `function (...) use (&$results) {/* modify $results */}`

Comment: I have been playing around with this and have managed to make it work - thank you!

Comment: @cHao i don't intend to modify the original array

Comment: @Baba: So....don't.  That's what `$results` is for  (Scuse me, you call it `$group`.)

Comment: La, la... @Baba Is there any way to make the random 'balanced' in the sense that they all show roughly equally? Probably a change to the `mt_rand(0, count($adverts) - 1)`...

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_filter to filter out only the elements that match your criteria, then use array rand to select a random one.

```
 $array = array_filter($array, function($el) use $location{
       return $el["location"] == $location;
 });

 if (count($array) > 1){
     $selected = $array(array_rand($array));
 } elseif (count($array) == 0){
     $selected = $array[0];
 } else {
     $selected = null;
 }
```

Note this requires php 5.3